How was Windows written?
It is a common knowledge that Windows kernel is written in C and Windows in C++.
I understand that the CPU can run Windows OS, because the compiled executable runs in machine code, not in C or C++.
My question is - at which point in history could we make our work easier by not having to write machine code, but instead could write a high-level language and have it compile into machine code?
To specify the question above - how can Windows kernel and Windows itself be written in C and C++, at which point was the development of Windows OS (or any OS) possible via a higher language?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_compiler_construction, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrapping_(compilers)

Probably a better question for retrocomputing.stackexchange.com.

The "Windows" angle to this question doesn't end up being very interesting, Windows was developed on a different OS (I think Xenix, a version of Unix), not "on itself" somehow. So it could have been developed in C right from the start.
